# Filter a dictionary before appending to a List

Tags: python

I have some processing, where in a loop, I am creating a dictionary and appending each dictionary to a list. And later I am doing something else with a list. Now, when I append a dictionary to a list - I want to make some CHECK - if it is true, append, if it is FALSE, just skip and don't append.

I made something simplified to make a point:

```
k = [1,2,3,4,5]

u = []
for i in k:
    x1 = i
    x2 = i**2

    # print(x1)
    my_dict = dict({'x1':x1,
                    'x2':x2})
    
    u.append(my_dict)

print(u)
# [{'x1': 1, 'x2': 1}, {'x1': 2, 'x2': 4}, {'x1': 3, 'x2': 9}, {'x1': 4, 'x2': 16}, {'x1': 5, 'x2': 25}]
```

Can you please help me fix the example above and do this: APPEND TO A LIST ONLY IF VALUE OF X2 is 9 OR 16. (skip others). (so I will be checking some key (x2) to have a value to be equal to some tuple of values (9, 16), which were input by argument to a function).

From this, I will be able to make it suitable for my case.

Comment: `if my_dict["x2"] in (9, 16): u.append(my_dict)`? Furthermore, you don't need to have `dict` to create a dictionary, the curly braces `{}` with key/value pairs is enough to create a dictionary.

Answer (score 3):

Lets try using a list comprehension with a `in` condition.

```
k = [1,2,3,4,5]
conditions = (9,16)

[{'x1':i, 'x2':i**2} for i in k if i**2 in conditions]
```

```
[{'x1': 3, 'x2': 9}, {'x1': 4, 'x2': 16}]
```

---

If you want to filter the list of `dicts` AFTER its been defined, to avoid recalculation of x2, you can do this -

```
k = [1,2,3,4,5]
conditions = (9,16)

u = [{'x1':i, 'x2':i**2} for i in k]

u2 = [i for i in u if i.get('x2') in conditions]
print(u2)
```

```
[{'x1': 3, 'x2': 9}, {'x1': 4, 'x2': 16}]
```

Comment: Except that it'll do calculation of `x2` value twice, I think it's important for OP

Comment: `u = [i for i in [{'x1':j, 'x2':j**2} for j in k] if i['x2'] in conditions]`

Comment: That's a great one-liner to do it! I avoided it since it might be difficult to understand for anyone learning. Thanks for the comment

Comment: I would avoid using `i.get('x2')` as you know for certain that the key will be there so it provides no advantage over `i['x2']` and it is less intuitive. And yes, doing the nested list-comprehension is less clear for new users, I agree.

Comment: `i['x2']` is definitely more intuitive, but [lacks proper error handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30363550/python-dict-getkey-versus-dictkey) and some neat default setting options! But you can definitely do it either ways.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
k = [1,2,3,4,5]

u = []
for i in k:
    x1 = i
    x2 = i**2

    # print(x1)
    my_dict = dict({'x1':x1,
                    'x2':x2})

    if my_dict['x2'] in [9, 16]:  # check if it equals 9 or 16
            u.append(my_dict)

print(u)
# [{'x1': 1, 'x2': 1}, {'x1': 2, 'x2': 4}, {'x1': 3, 'x2': 9}, {'x1': 4, 'x2': 16}, {'x1': 5, 'x2': 25}]
```